# How to calculate the probability of drawing at least a specific number of cards from given group(s) of cards?

Tags: c++, probability

Here's the deal, I cant find a way to put in code the calculations needed to calculate the probability of

- Drawing x cards from group A
- And y cards from group B simultaneously
- From a deck of cards which size is A+B+C.

As long as I am calculating the probability of a single group, there's no problem whatsoever, I cant figure out how to calculate the probability of drawing simultaneously from more than one group.

Ill link my repo from github: https://github.com/alebonch/CardCalc

This would be for a school project and I was trying to imitate Rustywolf's work https://github.com/Rustywolf/YugiohProbability , that you can find in use at https://www.yugioh.party/

EDIT:
P(A∩B) is the thing I gotta find how to calculate, but since the events are not independant, Im kind of lost.

This should be an Hypergeometric Calculator with more than one group to consider.

Comment: It is a mathematical question....

Comment: You can still brute-force to compute it (for reasonable numbers).

Comment: I did a format edit; not sure it adds clarity; feel free to revert it etc.  Can `C `be any random number like 527 or 32 etc.?  Can A or B be 0?

Comment: C can be any number from 0 to any. At the end of the day, the program should be used to calculate the probability of a card game, so it would be reasonable that the whole sum of A+B+C is between 40 and 60. If A or B is 0, the code works completely fine because it is like there is only one group, if both are 0, well, the probability should be 0. The problem is finding the P(A∩B) probability. I tried searching some similiar problems online but couldnt find any.

Comment: This is multivariate hypergeometric distribution, I believe

Comment: I would say A!/(A-x)! * (B-x)!/(B-y-x)! * (A+B+C-x-y)! / (A+B+C)!

Comment: @Sebastian Close, but you could still get draws from C. Please check my answer for proper distribution

Answer (score 0):

Ok, starting with [multivariate hypergeometric distribution](https://python.quantecon.org/multi_hyper.html), you want fixed draws for A and B but any draw from C. So you have to sum probabilities of multivariate hypergeometric distribution over draws from C

```
N = A + B + C
```

draws would be a, b, c

```
Pr(a, b, c | A, B, C) = (A,a) (B, b) (C, c) / (N, a+b+c)
```

where (A,a) is binomial coefficient.

So for a=x and b=y probabilities you sum

```
P(x,y) = Sum(c=[0...C]) Pr(x, y, c| A, B, C)
```

I could probably hack some C++ if you need/ask for it, but later

UPDATE

This is how binomial coefficients in C++ could be done, without overflow danger

```
#include <cmath>

auto binomC(int n, int k) -> double {
    return std::exp( std::lgamma(double(n) + 1.0) - std::lgamma(double(n-k) + 1.0) - std::lgamma(double(k) + 1.0));
}
```

And summing over C probably better be done in descending order, better preserve precision

```
P(x,y) = Sum(c=[C...0]) Pr(x, y, c| A, B, C)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ill try to do it myself, I couldnt figure out what was the type of the distribution I needed, I really appreciate the help, Ill make to sure to contact you in case Im not able to do it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Babboboncia you're welcome. I've added binomial coeff implementation which is better dealing with overflows and has no loops.